# Ajuda com excluir registro

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Tenho meu excluir funcionário porém dá esses erros:

**"Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\SitePHP\base\excluirFuncionario.php on line 6"**

**"PDO::exec() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\wamp\www\SitePHP\base\excluirFuncionario.php on line 8".**

Segue meu código:

```
require_once '../base/conexao.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$delete = $PDO->query("DELETE  FROM funcionario WHERE id = '$id' ");
$PDO->exec($delete);
if ($id){
    echo "<script>alert('Registro de Funcionario deletado');location.href = 'listarFuncionario.php';  </script>";
}else{
    echo "<script>alert('Ocorreu um erro no processo');location.href = 'listarFuncionario.php';  </script>";
}
```

```js
function excluir(id){
    if(confirm("Deseja excluir o registro?")){
        location.href = 'excluirFuncionario.php';
        
    }
}
```

```html
<?php while($funcionario = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><a href="excluirFuncionario.php" onkeyup="excluir(id)" onclick="excluir(<?php echo $funcionario['id'];?>)"><img src="../imagens/delete.png"></a></td>
         </tr>
         <?php }?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, não existe o índice `id` dentro no `$_GET`, verifique se você está passando corretamente!

Comment: Estou vendo se é algum problema na conexão, pois ele realmente não está buscando o ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não tá passando o ID na URL... Tenta assim:

```
function excluir(id){
    if(confirm("Deseja excluir o registro?")){
        location.href = 'excluirFuncionario.php?id=' + id;

    }
}

<?php while($funcionario = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><a href="#" onclick="excluir(<?php echo $funcionario['id'];?>)"><img src="../imagens/delete.png"></a></td>
         </tr>
         <?php }?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Warning: PDO::exec() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\wamp\www\SitePHP\base\excluirFuncionario.php on line 10

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\SitePHP\base\excluirFuncionario.php on line 7

Comment: Apresenta esses erros

Comment: @RuanRodrigues muda o `<a href=....` também!

Comment: Me ajudou bastante, agradeço! Abraço.